# Canceling a request when connection to client is lost

Tags: grails

I noticed that in a standard grails environment, a request is always executed to the end, even when the client connection is lost and the result can't be delivered anymore.

Is there a way to configure the environment in such a way that execution of a request is canceled as soon as the client connection is lost?

**Update:** Thanx fo the answers. Yes - most of the problems I am trying to avoid can be avoided by better coding:

- caching can make nearly every page fast
- a token can help to avoid submitting something twice

but there are some requests which still could consume some time. Let's take a map service as example. Calculating a route will take some time. One solution to avoid resubmitting the request could be a "calculationInProgress" flag together with a message to the user. But then it is still possible to create a lot of sessions and thus a lot of requests in order to do a DOS attack...

I am still curious: is there no way to configure the server to cancel the request? I used to develop on a system where the server behaved this way and it was great :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is no such way. And I'm sure grails (and your webcontainer) is designed to

1. accept incoming request
2. process it on server side
3. send response

if something happened during phase 2, i'll know about it only on send response phase. Actually you can send data to HttpSerlvetRespone by yourself, handle IOException, etc - but it will be too much low-level way, I think. And it will not help you with canceling your DB operations, while you're preparing data to send.

Btw, it's common pattern to use an web frontend, like nginx, that accepts incomming request and and handle all this problems with cancelled requests, slow requests (i guess it's the real problem?), etc.

Comment: Yes, slow requests are the real problem. Imagine a search which takes some time and an impatient user who reloads the page several times because she thinks that might help...

Comment: I think you can make a deal with this, by using Nginx and proper cache/etag headers, and some-server side caching (ehcache/memcache/etc)

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment it is reload and multiple clicks that you are trying to avoid. The proper technique should be to use Grails support for handling multiple form submissions:

http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#formtokens